# Queue object in ASP.NET web app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to ask you suggestion what is the best method to implement Queue objects list in ASP.NET app. I have one object(let's say ItemToQueue) which is created then user fill the web form. I would like to put ItemToQueue object to Queue object list and share this list between sessions. Users client-site script will send Ajax request to check is ItemToQueue object proceeded by separated thread or not in Queue object and will remove ItemToQueue.

Answer (score 1):

How about `ConcurrentQueue<T>`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

> Represents a thread-safe first in-first out (FIFO) collection.
>
> All public and protected members of ConcurrentQueue  are
>   thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads.